# Does any Hamiltonian that breaks time-reversal symmetry is isomorphic to a IQHE

Tags: topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry, quantum-hall-effect

The bulk Hamiltonian of the 2D Chern insulator in is given by
\begin{equation}
H=\sin k_{x}\sigma^{x}+\sin k_{y}\sigma^{y}+(2-m-\cos k_{x}-\cos k_{y})\sigma^{z}
\end{equation}
This Hamiltonian breaks the time-reversal symmetry. It is a lattice version of the IQHE. I was wondering if it make sense to think about whether all the 2D Hamiltonians, that breaks the time-reversal symmetry and are topologically non-trivial, are equivalent to IQHE? If it is true, is there any proof of this statement. Also I was wondering if it make sense to think about whether all the versions of the QHE are topologically equivalent or inequivalent. Thanks in advance for the comment.

Comment: As a minor comment, the Hamiltonian you wrote down is gapless. You need to change the parameters so it is actually an insulator.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. It is H=sinkx σx+sinky σy+(2−m-coskx−cosky) σz. The Hamiltonian is gapped except for m=0,2,4.